# An efficient way to grab the indexes for a two dimension list in python

Tags: python

I have this list:

```
my_list = [[1,2,3],
           [4,5,6],
           [7,8,9]]
```

And I want the index for, let's say number nine. It would be (2,2). I want an efficient and less verbose way to get the x,y indexes and I tried this:

```
def my_indexes(the_list):
    (i_s, j_s) = [[(i, j) for j, cell in enumerate(row) if cell == 9] for i, row in enumerate(the_list) if 9 in row][0][0]
    return (i_s, j_s)

my_indexes(my_list)
(2, 2)
```

It works but perhaps my approach is overcomplicated. Please, could you help me with a better approach? Thank you.

Comment: First you import ```numpy```  like ```import numpy as np``` then ```np_list = np.array(my_list)``` then                                                                            ```print(np.argwhere(np_list == 9))```

Comment: My mistake, I tagged it as numpy but I want a base python solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use this.

```
n = 9
[(i, sub_list.index(n)) for i, sub_list in enumerate(my_list) if n in sub_list]
```

I got the output as `[(2,2)]` for your input.

This returns a list of tuples with indexes of all occurrences. If you need only the first occurrence you can break the iteration on the first encounter. I couldn't think of a much simpler one

Comment: Thank you @Jonath Sujan, this comprehension list works fine!

Comment: @Alexis Great :)

Answer (score 1):

Since this is tagged numpy, I'll give you the numpy solution

```
np_list = np.array(my_list)                                                                                         
np.argwhere(np_list == 9)

array([[2, 2]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Thank you @David Kaftan, but it was my mistake to put the tag numpy (I edited my question). Please, do you know how I can do that in basic python?

Comment: I wish I had a better answer for you, but I think the way you did it in the example is how I would do it if I were constrained to not use numpy.